# php doesn't read value in form

Tags: php, forms

(NEW)I've used some of the suggested noted below, and in going through my code I noticed a couple other serious things that need to be fixed. I've decided to correct all and revisit this post if I need to in the future.

(OLD)I set the values of my html form to fill with text that I am calling from a database. That works. I also have PHP in the form to POST form values to my database. That works when the form values aren't set. What am I missing to connect the two? I want the form to be prefilled, and it's like they are not talking to each other because when I test to see if the form is empty, it doesn't recognize the fields.

My form:

```
    <form action="user-profile-test.php" method="post">
<p>First Name: <br><input type="text" name="first_name" size="15" maxlength="20" value="<?=$user['first_name']?><?php if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

The PHP $user query:

```
$user = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']}")->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: not related to your question but you must use _(underscore) in place of -(dash) giving file name like `user-profile-test.php` to `user_profile_test.php`

Comment: i dont understand ur question ??

Comment: i also not able to understand it

Comment: @hmcka Add your server side example where you are taking post values from form.

Comment: @Vicky NO! Dashes are perfectly legal for file names.

Comment: ty nl-x. I had to pull away from this assignment to go to work work. I am doing more online searches, and it seems that a better way to ask the question is... how do I prepopulate a form with data that I've pulled from mySQL database. Currently, the form works exactly as expected when I submit it not prepoplated, however, when I add a value that pulled the data from my database, my form validation says that the form fields are not filled. But yes they are because I can see the data that's filled from the db.

Comment: I am also going to re-search StackOverflow with the new terms I've learned.

Answer (score 0):

If your `value=""` attribute is present then the `$_POST` will send it to your script so it is good practice to apply some validation to the form either prior to submission or on submission to the PHP script (`user-profile-test.php`)

Option 1

User a library such as JQuery Validatation (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to intercept the submission of the form and feedback to the user if a value is empty and is required to be completed.

Option 2

IN the `user-profile-test.php` check to see if the post variable `$_POST['first_name]` is empty and if so return an error.

Lastly with regard to the database value I would use the following in the `input` attribute `value`.

```
<?php if(isset($user['first_name'])) { echo $user['first_name']; } ?>
```

Comment: Option 1... I am trying to stay away from the JQuery to up my understanding of PHP. Option 2... I tried that input attribute and received an error.

Comment: Ok. But then I found your edited version of the code. It is definitely cleaner, Ty. I am still getting my original issue, however. I can see that the fields are prepopulated, but my form validation says that the form fields are not filled.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good practice to **sanitize** data before inserting on a web page (and before any output has been echoed).

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) // Check if first_name was posted from a form
        $first_name = htmlentities( $_POST['first_name'] );
    elseif ( isset( $user ) && isset( $user['first_name'] ) ) // Otherwise, take it from the database
        $first_name = htmlentities( $user['first_name'] );
    else // If none of the above, leave it as an empty string so PHP won't complain
        $first_name = '';
?>

<form action="user-profile-test.php" method="post">
    First name: <br />
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" /><!-- Here PHP won't complain, since $first_name is already defined -->
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Submit your data" />
</form>
```

Now, why `htmlentities()`? This way, if you enter a weird character (like an `>`), it will be encoded with an equivalent that won't break your HTML.

Also note that I checked first if `$user` exists before checking if `$user['first_name']` exists. If you do this: `isset( $user['first_name'] )` with an inexistent `$user`, PHP will give you an error.

Comment: I did some "sanitization". Ty. I've noticed, however, that I am still having the same issue with the code. I also noticed a couple other things that I should change. I've decided to correct all and revisit this post if I need to in the future.